# I can't find any file in the Assets folder

Tags: android

I have a tar.gz file [1.5 MB size] into assets folder and I'm trying to move it to /data/data//.
I'm trying to do this in a secondary activity (not in the main activity).
The code:

```
 try {
        Log.d("chiri", Arrays.toString(getAssets().list(".")));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        InputStream fileInput = getAssets().open("nmap.tar.gz");
        OutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.example.pentesting/nmap.tar.gz");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fileInput.read(buffer))>0){
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
} catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("chiri", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
}
```

The problem is `getAssets` seems to be empty.

I saw that there are many topics on this problem but I couldn't figure out where is my problem. I saw that this can be a problem because the file is bigger then 1MB but i tried the think with a .txt file of 300bytes, but I couldn't find it too.

Any idea ?

Comment: i think you are giving wrong path

Comment: What do you mean? the wrong path for what? the log.d("chiri", arrays ....) returns an empty result. I mean my app can't find any file into the assets folder.

Comment: i mean you are giving wrong path to fileInput i.e inputstream

Comment: the getAssets() method shouldn't return the files which are copied into the assets folder in the project navigation panel ?

Comment: try with this for retrieving the strean from assert folder InputStream fileInput=FileInputStream("file:///assets/nmap.tar.gz");

Comment: it give me error to create the FileInputStream method

Comment: I managed to use your line of code @santhosh but it still trows the file not found exception: 12-27 06:02:34.051: E/chiri(13580): /file:/assets/nmap.tar.gz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: sorry for that InputStream fileInput=FileInputStream("file:///android_assets/nmap.tar.gz")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct path to the assets folder should be specified like this.

> file:///android_asset/nmap.tar.gz

And then you should be able to access the file.

**The other way, which you are trying also would work:**

Fix this line, by removing the dot, and you will see the list of files get printed.

```
Log.i("chiri", Arrays.toString(getAssets().list("")));
```

Comment: hmmm yes you were right about the log stuff but the problem why my app wasn't seen my archive it was because because my app reads only nmap.tar not nmap.tar.gz from assets folder now I made it thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.zip` instead of `.tar.gz`, it worked for me.